# E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list (Component)

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I started a new class and I am new in using Linux. I use debian and I follow to teacher guide to install git and docker. I entered all the commands in the terminal until I had some error.

1. `sudo apt install git` worked
2. 

```
git config --global user.name "Ion Popescu"
git config --global user.email "ion.popescu@gmail.com"
git config --global core.editor vim
git config --global core.pager more
git config --global help.autocorrect true
```

all worked

3. `sudo apt-get -y remove docker docker-engine docker.io` worked
4. 

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates wget
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common ssh
```

worked all of them

5.

```
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
sudo apt-key add gpg
```

worked

6. `echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` worked

Now I have to enter these lines but I get an error after the first one

7.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt -y install docker-ce
```

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make sure that `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` is formatted correctly use the following command (`tee` without `-a` to override the source):

On debian Buster:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

On debian Stretch:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

(You can use `$(lsb_release -cs)` instead of debian codename which require `lsb-release` package to be installed.)

An alternative way to add `docker-ce` repository: You have already installed `software-properties-common`, you can use `add-apt-repository` to add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

[Docker-ce docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/)

Comment: printf on linux terminal overwrides the data on a file?

Comment: Works for Ubuntu

Comment: it works for me (ubuntu 20.04 focal): 
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me :

```
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  focal stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null`
```

The problem is with the variable `$(lsb_release -cs)`, in linux it returns something like `una` (at least on Mint 20.3). I don't think there is a special repository for mint so you must hard code it. I was following the official doc, but also read [this forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-cant-add-docker-repository-mint-ulyssa/108585/5) where it was mentioned that you also need to delete the current docker list available in `/etc/apt/sources.listd/docker.list`.